# XSLT output method "xml" not showing html tags as html ouput

Tags: xml, xslt

In xsltransform scenario, we have xsl with declaration as below:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
version="2.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
```

```
 <xsl:output method="xml" />
```

XML has data, but xsl has `<table><tr><td></td></tr></table>` interlined with xslt logic.

**Issue:** table tags are shown when inspected in Chrome browser but only text in table shown on webpage(html output) but not rendered as table.

When set `<xsl:output method="html" />`, the entire data comes as text without `<table>` tags.

Any clue around this problem?

Comment: Does Chrome apply the XSLT? Or do you run that outside of the browser? Please provide minimal but complete samples of XSLT, XML, wanted output (is that mixed namespace arbitrary XML with some XHTML tables mixed in or a simple and complete XHTML document) and result document you currently get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The XHTML namespace is the one you had in the first version of your question, now you have changed it to use the namespace `http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40` which is not something any browser will recognize in X(HT)ML as it has no W3C defined meaning. So the `table` elements in that namespace `http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40` are just elements in a namespace unknown to the browser and therefore are of course not rendered with HTML semantics. Use the XHTML namespace `http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml` for any elements in XML you want to be recognized as XHTML elements.